# line, = ax.plot(x,y)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know the meaning of the **","** after **"line"**.

```
line, = ax.plot(rand(100), rand(100), 'o', picker=line_picker)
```

It seems important to the code.
Without the "," my code crushed.
The error is "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_xdata'"

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class PointBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print('click', event)
        ind = event.ind[0]
        self.xs.remove(self.xs[ind])
        self.ys.remove(self.ys[ind])
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line = ax.plot(demag_data["X corr"], demag_data['Y corr']*-1, 'o',color='tab:blue', picker=5)
linebuilder = PointBuilder(line)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It is just to express the fact that the ax.plot return a list and you consider that there is one element in the list (and so you take it instead of the list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The introduction: Unpacking lists:*

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
first, second, third = lst    # first == 1, second == 2, third == 3; "unpacking" a list

lst = [1, 2]                  
first, second = lst           # first == 1, second == 2

list = [1]
first, = lst                  # first == 1

first = lst                   # first == [1]   # not the same as previous
```

---

`ax.plot()` returns  a *list* of Line2D objects representing the plotted data.

So, after the command

```
line = ax.plot(...)
```

you will have in the `line` variable a *list* (of only one element), but you need this element, not the list.

You may do `line = line[0]` after this command, but `line, = ax.plot(...)` is nicer (more Pythonic).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a feature to ensure that a function returns one non-iterable object or an iterable object with only one element. Here is an example:

```
def func():
   return 1, 2, 3

a, b, c = func()
```

This works fine. Consider now the following example:

```
a = func()
```

This fork fine as well, but `a` is now a tuple collecting all the outputs. The output of `print(a)` is `(1, 2, 3)`. Let us add the comma:

```
a, = func()
```

This does not work, it gives an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

But when we change the function so it outputs a single object

```
def func():
   return 1
```

or

```
def func():
   return [1]
```

it works again.

**The additional functionality of this syntax, which is important here, is the following: if the function outputs a list with only one element it takes this element from the list and outputs it.** For instance:

```
def func():
   return [1]

a = func()
print(a)
```

The output is `[1]`. For the case with comma:

```
a, = func()
print(a)
```

the output is `1`.

So the authors don't want this function to output the list with more than one element, and they want to output this one element itself, not as an element of the list.

Comment: I guess, you forgot the comma in your last code example. I would have fixed it but so wants me to edit at least six characters.